# Is there a deeper meaning when a number is squared?

Tags: intuition, physics, dimensional-analysis

In my opinion, math is about more than just memorizing equations, it's about numbers that are built in a way that represents our understanding of something.

So I ask this, what does it mean intuitively when you square a number?

Consider the equations in Physics like:

The force between two charged particles $F_m=\frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{R^2}$

Yes, I'm sure there is a proof out there which describes how this expression was derived, but what I want to know is can you look at the equation and understand what it means when a number is squared?

Or, is this not a way in which we can look at math? I mean to say that, math isn't meant to be interpreted like that.

Another equation to consider is the equation of kinetic energy:

$E_k = 1/2\cdot m\cdot v^2$

I would really like to develop a deeper understanding of math so I can more easily interpret Physics equations.

Comment: Philosophy SE. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I think that's a little too broad? Squares can have so many interpretations. When it's in a formula (e.g. $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$), I just tend to interpret it as: "A 'small' variation in $v$ will cause a 'big' variation in $E_k$", or "if my velocity keeps getting higher, my kinetic energy will also keep getting higher, but at a much higher rate".

Comment: In Physics though, units have a specific meaning which relates the equation to the real world. Like a joule is equal to Kilograms * meters squared over seconds squared J = (Kg*m^2/s^2).

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar are you sure Philosophy would be a better place to ask this? This is regarding mathematics, and I have narrowed it down to a single aspect (the understanding of a number squared). I believe experienced mathematicians could have valuable input here.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone A 'small' variation in v will cause a 'big' variation in Ek is wrong - a small variation in $v$ will cause a variation of a smaller order, as is demonstrated by expanding $(v+\Delta v)^2-v^2$: $$(v+\Delta v)^2-v^2=2v\Delta v+(\Delta v)^2$$ Since $(\Delta v)^2\approx 0$, and $v\Delta v$ is smaller than $v$.

Comment: @Klik This is more philosophy than math. First off, this question isn't very mathematically phrased. You seem to want an "understanding", which is what philosophy gives. There are other intuition questions - compare them to yours. They are more advanced, and ask for intuition of more advanced concepts. Your question asks for a deeper understanding of a very simple concept, and so would be fit on Philosopy SE.

Comment: If I may have to motivate squaring, the Euclidean geometry is the first thing that comes to my mind. It kind of explains $F_m = \frac{GMm}{R^2}$, but doesn't quite explain $E_k = \frac 12mv^2$ though. $\frac 12[\text{something}]^2$ seems to arise more intuitively from integration.

Comment: Hence why I said 'small', and not small. Of course if the variation is less than one then the square of that will be even smaller. That was a completely non-rigorous way of putting it (I'd have to define what small means in first place), but since we're talking about intuitions, I thought I'd share how I think about squares (or powers in general).

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Yes, of course. For me, intuition is a geometric interpretation, and so, my dear OP, if you're like me, see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702414/what-is-exponentiation/702430#702430). Might this be a duplicate?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar "A 'small' variation in v will cause a 'big' variation in Energy". The change in $v$ is $\delta v$, but the change in energy is definitely larger $2v\delta v$

Comment: @tpb261 Yes, but since $\Delta v$ is small, $2v\Delta v$ can be compared to $\Delta v$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar it again depends on the values. from v=100 to v=101, the change in energy is very high compared to that in velocity, while at v=0.5 to 0.6, it's not so high. Also, I feel comparing the changes is not "proper". The relative changes make more sense. The % change in velocity is half that in energy, so I guess it is "big". I just felt we needed a bit more "clarity" on things, here.

Comment: @tpb261 Yeah, I agree on that.

Comment: So the gravity thing - this is because we live in a 2D world.  The "gravity" is spread out over an area proportional to $r^2$ at a distance $r$, because the surface area of a sphere is proportional to $r^2$.

Comment: As to energy being something squared - one way to look at it is because $\frac12 x^2$ is the indefinite integral of $x$.

Comment: But actually I think there is also a strong connection with the concept of "orthogonality," which in essence is Pythagoras’s theorem.  That is, given a point in space, then its distance from the origin is the square root of the sum of the squares of its coordinates.  That is, it isn't the cube root of the sum of the cubes, nor anything else for that matter.

So if you have a sound wave, then its total energy is the integral over time of the amplitude squared.  But because of the Pythagoras thing, at also ends up being one half of the sum of the squares of the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: For this reason, I have thought that the importance of the number 2 (or squaring) via higher dimensional generalizations of Pythagoras’s Theorem could be considered one of the big ideas coming from the Nineteenth Century.

Comment: @Stephen: "We live in a 2D world"???

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, how on earth could this be off-topic? Giving algebraic quantities geometric and/or physical interpretations is how we get better at the algebra. As far as I know, most algebra wasn't discovered by mere symbol pushing; it was discovered using geometric and/or physical principles.

Comment: I think [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-quadratically-not-linearly-with-speed) may help you.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Exactly, I would like to think that squaring a number is more than just the area of a square. Orthogonality is definitely a meaning which can be applied to squaring a number. MJD's answer below also has some good points regarding dividing by the distance squared. I am looking for a deeper meaning to apply it to a better understanding of units used in Physics. Like the Joule (as mentioned above). 1 J = 1 kg*m^2/s^2) or the Newton (1 N = 1 Kg*m/s^2). There is another approach to understanding these units, which is by considering each unit one at a time.

Comment: It could be understood that 1 Newton = mass (kg) * acceleration (m/s^2). Acceleration = velocity (m/s) / time (s). Therefore 1 Newton is the force of accelerating 1 kg of mass by 1 m/s per second. Moreover, 1 Joule is equal to applying 1 Newton of force over a distance of 1 meter. It can be broken down and understood just as proofs can be used to describe Pythagorean's theorem. A holistic understanding--one that does not consider the parts to be separate--is what I'm after, though I'm not sure whether this is possible or whether equations have no meaning if not purposefully constructed.

Comment: I'd say that the "squared" in kinetic energy is a matter of modulus. Every time you don't need the direction of the vector, the most natural thing to take is its square modulus. In physics, in probability, in geometry, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there is a general statement you can make about the physical meaning of a quantity squared; such quantities appear in too many different contexts.

But the physical meaning of the $R^2$ in the denominator of universal gravitation equation that you quoted is very deep indeed. It's there because:

1. We live in a three-dimensional universe
2. Energy is conserved

Consider a mass, say the Earth.  The gravitational effect of the Earth on some other mass is a constant.  Suppose the gravitational effect of the Earth at some distance, say $d$, is a certain amount.  At twice the distance from the Earth, distance $2d$, the gravitational effect is spread over a sphere which has twice the radius of the one at distance $d$, and so has four times the area.  So the gravitational effect at distance $2d$ is only one-fourth the effect at distance $d$.  Similarly the effect at distance $3d$ is spread over a sphere 9 times as large, and so is only one-ninth as great at any point on that sphere.  This is the physical meaning of the $R^2$ in the denominator.

The $R^2$ appears in the denominator of many similar force-related formulas.  For example, the [electrostatic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_law) exerted by a point charge at distance $R$ is also proportional to $\frac1{R^2}$, for the same reason.

Similarly, the intensity of a sound at distance $R$ is proportional to $\frac1{R^2}$, and the intensity of light at distance $R$ is proportional to $\frac1{R^2}$, and the intensity of an explosion at distance $R$ is proportional to $\frac1{R^2}$.

If the universe were four-dimensional, the $R^2$ in the denominator would be an $R^3$ instead; if the universe were two-dimensional, it would be an $R^1$ instead.  In similar situations where the universe under consideration is *effectively* two-dimensional, as when considering the intensity of ripples on the surface of a pond, the intensity is proportional not to $\frac1{R^2}$ but to $\frac 1{R^1}$.  Similarly, the 
electrostatic force exerted by a very long, thin current-carrying wire is proportional to $\frac 1{R^1}$ rather than $\frac 1{R^2}$.  An explosion at one end of a long tunnel does *not* decrease in intensity proportional to $\frac 1{R^2}$; the force at the other end is about the same as the force near the explosion, because the long narrow tunnel is effectively one-dimensional, so the force is proportional to $\frac1{R^0}$, which is constant.

Answer (score 1):

MJD's answer for the square appearance is the classical one and very good, but I wanted to just add some points around your wider question.

First, physicists for hundreds of years have explained the square as the area of the sphere of influence of the force at that distance.  Kant even, in his Prolegomena, says that natural laws MUST have this form by logical necessity even though it is a synthetic proposition, and is one of the big examples of synthetic a priori.  When electrical forces were found to have the same form, many took it as obvious and well understood.

Now days, though, we know these laws are actually wrong.  General relativity gives corrections to gravity that change the expression, as does (the relativistic) Maxwellian unification of electromagnetism (due finite propagation of the force).  Kant is pretty much a laughing stock of hubris, and physicists no longer believe you can give those kinds of simplistic explanations based just on what you do to numbers.  This is why you won't find many mathematicians willing to jump on answering your question.

Instead, science works the other way.  It builds models that describe how to think about phenomena, with an ontology of things and their transformations.  Then they derive equations for that model.  By selecting different models and checking predictions, they get better equations over time.  But they try not to ascribe some magical reason or meaning to why the equations take a given form outside the model.

There is however, some sense in looking at multiplying and dividing quantities.  Unit analysis tells scientists what they are measuring.  You have to be able to measure things consistently, or measurement is meaningless.  If you are measuring mass and want to test it, you must test it against a theory that predicts a quantity convertible to mass.  So when you see the $v^2$ in the kinetic energy, understand that you will expect units of kg $m^2 s^{-2}$ for energy, so it's at least understandable.  But to get these equations, you need a model, and classical physics uses Hamiltonian or Langrangean models on Poisson manifolds.

Of course, like the gravity equation, the kinetic energy equation was also found wrong years ago, first with special relativity.  So again, just be careful looking for meaning outside a model, and expect to be wrong in the long term.

Comment: I think you've hit the key point in this question, which is if mathematics can be interpreted in the sense described or if it only has meaning when it is modeled after our understanding of something. I would like to think there is a sort of geometric understanding that goes because the two dimensional area of a square. In any case I will take a look at Kant's Prolegomena. Would you suggest any specific search terms so I may get better research results?

Comment: @Klik: The full title is "Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics That Will Be Able To Present Itself As A Science" by Immanuel Kant.  It was his "hey, why isn't anyone reading my Critique of Pure Reason" Cliff's Notes version of his rational philosophy.  It's available http://web.mnstate.edu/gracyk/courses/phil%20306/kant_materials/prolegomena1.htm in the public domain.  Sections 37 and 38 of "Second part of the main transcendental problem" show him repeating the common reasoning of his time here on the spherical area and forces.