# Derive the p-test if p is an irrational number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I would like some help with this problem.  I've been given that we have a $k^p$  s.t. $p$ is irrational and $k$ is a positive integer satisfies the following:

1. $k^r\lt k^p$ if $r$ is positive and rational while $p$ is positive and irrational and $r\lt p$. and
2. $k^r \gt k^p$ if $p\lt r$ for positive $p$ and $r$.

I need to derive the $p$ test for $p$ being irrational by using the following:

1. validity of the $p$ test when $p$ is rational
2. Comparison test for series
3. Denseness of rationals.

How would I go about doing this? What I have done is that I have taken $k^p$ and $k^r$  both their inverses because this is the only way we could use the comparison test.  But beyond this I'm not sure where any of it leads to.

Comment: You might check that my changes maintain what you intended to say

Comment: You will need $k \gt 1$ for the inequalities to be strict.

Comment: For a series, you can use the integral test to show it true for any real number, rational or not.

Comment: Might [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702414) be of any help ?

Comment: you see @Lucian I'm not allowed to use logarithms, otherwise I would've known how to do it.